# Rails 3 - Column Names (Legacy Database)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, legacy-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alias for column names in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014831/alias-for-column-names-in-rails)

I'm writing a module of ActiveRecord models to access a MySQL legacy database. My problem is that the database has a column naming convention that looks like this: `groupID`, `metaGroupName`, `flagName`. Is there an easy way to make the models play nice with this naming convention?

**Update:**
I'd like to avoid the `alias_attribute` method if possible. It's not a small database, and that would be a lot of columns to alias. Is there a method in ActiveRecord that interprets column names that I can override, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to keep repeating yourself—that's good. Fortunately, Ruby makes it rather easy. Try something like the following:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  column_names.each do |cn|
    alias_attribute cn.underscore.intern, cn
  end

end
```

I'd then factor that out into a `Module` maybe like so:

```
module AliasLegacyColumns
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    column_names.each {|cn|
      alias_attribute cn.underscore.intern, cn
    }
  end

end
```

Then just include that in your models as necessary. For further refinement I would provide an `alias_columns` class-level method that accepts parameters such as `:include` or `:exclude` so you can monkey-patch `ActiveRecord::Base` with said module but only call `alias_columns` as needed per model.

Comment: That works well. I have one more problem; I also added this alias for the primary key: `alias_attribute(:id, primary_key) unless primary_key.nil?`. But, if I try something like `LegacyModel.select(:id)`, I get a MySQL error that the 'id' column does not exist. It looks like Relation is not using the alias. It may be the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4433374/440292). `LegacyModel.find(some_id)` and `LegacyModel.first.id` both work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your model

```
alias_attribute :new_column_name, :myLegacyColumnName
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do that for every column in every table? It's not a small database...